# Data Conversion error while inserting into a new table from a joint statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing a simple insert from a join of 4 tables.
When I select the columns from the join , they work seamlessly.
However when I try to insert into my newly created table I get the following message

"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'White' to data type int."

This is most likely coming from the "Race" column which is in the Dim_Borrower table.

In the Dim_Borrower The race column is varchar (50)
I created the Race columns as varchar (50) in my new table.

Trying to understand why I am getting this error and how to solve the issue.

Below is my Query

```
Create Table Param_Data(



 LoanAmount int,
   [Purpose of Loan] varchar (50),
   PropertyUsage varchar (50),
   MonthlyIncome int,
   MaritalStatus varchar (50),
   Race varchar (50),
   Ethnicity varchar (50),
   Sex varchar (50),
   LoanDate datetime,
   DOB datetime,
   )
   Insert into Param_Data
   select a.LoanAmount,a.MonthlyIncome,c.[Property Usage], d.Race, d.Ethnicity,d.Sex, d.MaritalStatus, d.DOB, b.LoanDate, b.[Purpose of Loan]
            FROM        dbo.Fact_Financials a
            LEFT JOIN   dbo.Dim_Loan b
            ON          a.Loan_ID = b.Loan_ID
            LEFT JOIN   Dim_Property c
            ON          a.Property_ID = c.Property_ID
            LEFT JOIN   dbo.Dim_Borrower d
            ON          a.Borrower_ID = d.Borrower_ID
```

I am stuck tried dropping and recreating, checked to make sure the race column was varchar in both destination table and original table.

Comment: The 4th column in the table `Param_Data` is `MonthlyIncome int` but the 4th column that you try to insert is `d.Race`. Is `d.Race` integer?

Comment: Your `create table` statement is not correct because there is a trailing comma.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you should list the columns in your SELECT statement in order of the INSERT columns list. But there is no column list for you INSERT.
Also you can use a SELECT INTO statement so a table will be automatically created and you won't have these problems

```
select a.LoanAmount
,a.MonthlyIncome
,c.[Property Usage]
, d.Race
, d.Ethnicity
,d.Sex
, d.MaritalStatus
, d.DOB
, b.LoanDate
, b.[Purpose of Loan]
INTO Param_data          
FROM        dbo.Fact_Financials a
            LEFT JOIN   dbo.Dim_Loan b
            ON          a.Loan_ID = b.Loan_ID
            LEFT JOIN   Dim_Property c
            ON          a.Property_ID = c.Property_ID
            LEFT JOIN   dbo.Dim_Borrower d
            ON          a.Borrower_ID = d.Borrower_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

List the column explicitly when doing the `INSERT`.  Then be sure the columns line up!  SQL uses the *positions* of columns in an `INSERT`, not their names.  (This can be counter-intuitive because SQL usually relies on names, not positions to identify columns.)

Yours do not line up:

```
INSERT into Param_Data (LoanAmount, [Purpose of Loan], PropertyUsage, MonthlyIncome,
                        MaritalStatus, Race, Ethnicity, Sex,
                        LoanDate, DOB
                       )
    SELECT ff.LoanAmount, ff.MonthlyIncome,
           p.[Property Usage], d.Race, d.Ethnicity, d.Sex, d.MaritalStatus, d.DOB,
           l.LoanDate, l.[Purpose of Loan]
    FROM dbo.Fact_Financials ff LEFT JOIN
         dbo.Dim_Loan l
         ON ff.Loan_ID = l.Loan_ID LEFT JOIN
         Dim_Property p
         ON ff.Property_ID = p.Property_ID LEFT JOIN
         dbo.Dim_Borrower b
         ON ff.Borrower_ID = b.Borrower_ID;
```

You need to re-arrange the columns -- I prefer to rearrange them in the `SELECT` rather than the `INSERT`:

```
INSERT into Param_Data (LoanAmount, [Purpose of Loan], PropertyUsage, MonthlyIncome,
                        MaritalStatus, Race, Ethnicity, Sex,
                        LoanDate, DOB
                       )
    SELECT ff.LoanAmount, l.[Purpose of Loan], p.[Property Usage], ff.MonthlyIncome,
           d.MaritalStatus, d.Race, d.Ethnicity, d.Sex,
           l.LoanDate, d.DOB
    FROM dbo.Fact_Financials ff LEFT JOIN
         dbo.Dim_Loan l
         ON ff.Loan_ID = l.Loan_ID LEFT JOIN
         Dim_Property p
         ON ff.Property_ID = p.Property_ID LEFT JOIN
         dbo.Dim_Borrower b
         ON ff.Borrower_ID = b.Borrower_ID;
```

Notice that I also changed the table aliases to be *meaningful* -- abbreviations for the table names.  This makes the query easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Rookie mistake. Suggestions fixed the issue.